# Tabulator: Is it possible to add custom column with calculated value for each row?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabulator

Is it possible to add custom column with calculated value for each row? So if col 1 have value "3" and col 2 have value "5" then i want dynamic col 3 with sum value of 8.

I'm using Vue Tabulator. Here is my Table.vue component.

```
<template>
    <div v-if="tabledata" class="w-full p-3 border border-gray-200 shadow-xl rounded-lg  mt-10">
        <VueTabulator id="usersData" v-model="tabledata" :options="options" />
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            tabledata: [
                {
                    "name": "Hron",
                    "lvl2": 5,
                    "lvl3": 0,
                    "score": 5
                },
                {
                    "name": "Zhr",
                    "lvl2": 2,
                    "lvl3": 1,
                    "score": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "Mang",
                    "lvl2": 4,
                    "lvl3": 1,
                    "score": null
                }
            ],
            options: {
                layout:"fitColumns",
                columns: [
                    {title:"S#", formatter:"rownum", width:70, align:"center", responsive:3},
                    {title:"Name", field:"name", minWidth:150},
                    {title:"Lvl 2", field:"lvl2", sorter:"number", align:"center", formatter:"money", formatterParams:{precision:false}, bottomCalc:"sum", minWidth:80},
                    {title:"Lvl 3", field:"lvl3", sorter:"number", align:"center", formatter:"money", formatterParams:{precision:false}, bottomCalc:"sum", minWidth:80},
                    {title:"Score", field:"score", sorter:"number", align:"center", formatterParams:{precision:true}, bottomCalc:"avg"}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And i want data output look like this inside table.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Hron",
    "lvl2": 5,
    "lvl3": 0,
    "score": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "Zhr",
    "lvl2": 2,
    "lvl3": 1,
    "score": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "Mang",
    "lvl2": 4,
    "lvl3": 1,
    "score": 5
  }
]
```

I have been looking into documentation but was not able to find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use a ***mutator*** to achieve this.

If we start with some sample data containing the two columns with values

```js
var data = [
    {col1:27, col2:55}
];
```

Then define a custom mutator function that calculates the sum of these two rows

```js
var customMutator = function(value, data, type, params, component){
    //value - original value of the cell
    //data - the data for the row
    //type - the type of mutation occurring  (data|edit)
    //params - the mutatorParams object from the column definition
    //component - when the "type" argument is "edit", this contains the cell component for the edited cell, otherwise it is the column component for the column

    return data.col1 + data.col2 ; //return the sum of the other two columns.
}
```

Then in our column definition we add our third column with a made up **field** name and set the mutator function on the ***mutator*** property:

```js
columns:[
    {title:"Column 1", field:"col1"},
    {title:"Column 2", field:"col2"},
    {title:"Sum Column", field:"sumCol", mutator:customMutator}, //make column the sum of the other two columns
]
```

Full details can be found in the [Mutator Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/mutators#mutators)

Comment: I tried this, but the mutator function does not get called when I modify the values on the other two cells